# Why does this script run slow in Google Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I've written a script that loads images dynamically. A popup with the image will show when you click on the image.

Does anyone have any idea why this scripts runs slow **in Google Chrome.**

I've tested so far in Internet Explorer, Edge, Firefox and Opera where the exact same script runs without any problem.

```css
body.noscroll{
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}

.image-popup div:after {
    content: "X";
    top: 9px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 43px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    
}

.image-popup img {
    height: 95%;
    margin: 1.25% auto;
}

.image-popup .navbtn {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100vh;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Just Another Hand';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.image-popup .navbtn#prev {
    margin-left: -37px;
    background: url(https://files.casa-elcorasueno.com/image/btn_prev.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    width: 15px;
}

.image-popup .navbtn#next {
    margin-left: 17px;
    background: url(https://files.casa-elcorasueno.com/image/btn_next.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    width: 15px;
}


.image-popup {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
    z-index: 2;
}

.image-popup div {
    height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}


  .photos {
    width: 1040px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.photos:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}




.photos div {
    width: 256px;
    float: left;
    height: 260px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-size: cover !important;
}



.photos div button {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    width: 256px;
    height: 260px;
    background: url('https://files.casa-elcorasueno.com/image/enlarge.png') #0000007a;
    background-size: 25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<span id="pageName">Voorbeeld</span>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$images = [
"https://files.casa-elcorasueno.com/image/kamers/sol/sol_1.jpg",
"https://files.casa-elcorasueno.com/image/kamers/sol/sol_2.jpg",
"https://files.casa-elcorasueno.com/image/kamers/sol/sol_3.jpg",
"https://files.casa-elcorasueno.com/image/kamers/sol/sol_6.jpg",
"https://files.casa-elcorasueno.com/image/kamers/sol/sol_5.jpg",
"https://files.casa-elcorasueno.com/image/kamers/sol/sol_4.jpg",
"https://files.casa-elcorasueno.com/image/kamers/sol/sol_7.jpg",
"https://files.casa-elcorasueno.com/image/kamers/sol/sol_8.jpg"
];

$(window).on("load")
{
    
$box = $("<section></section>");
$currentId = 0;
$($box).addClass("photos");
$box.insertAfter("#pageName");
$popup = $('<div class="image-popup"></div>');

$popup_sub = $("<div></div>");

$($popup).append($popup_sub);

$("body").prepend($popup);

$popupimg = $('<img src="">');
$prevbtn = $('<span class="navbtn" id="prev"></span>');
$nextbtn = $('<span class="navbtn" id="next"></span>');

$($popup_sub).append($prevbtn);
$($popup_sub).append($popupimg);
$($popup_sub).append($nextbtn);



for($i = 0; $i < $images.length; $i++)
{
    
    
    $elem = $("<div></div>");
    $btn = $("<button></button>");
    $btn.attr("data-id",$i);
    $subelem = $($elem).append($btn);
    
    $($elem).css("background", "url('" + $images[$i] +  "')");
    
    if(($i+1)%4 == 0)
    {
         $($elem).css("margin-right", "0px");
    
    }
    
    
    $($box).append($elem);
}

}

$(".photos div button").on("click", function(e){
    
$currentId = parseInt($(this).attr("data-id"));
$url = $images[$(this).attr("data-id")];

$($popupimg).attr("src",$url);

$(".image-popup").fadeIn().addClass("open");
$("body").addClass("noscroll");
   
})
    
$(".image-popup div").after().on("click", function(){
$(".image-popup").fadeOut().removeClass("open");
$("body").removeClass("noscroll");

    
});
    
    
    $(".image-popup .navbtn#next").on("click", function(e){
        
        e.stopPropagation();
        
        
        if($currentId >= $images.length - 1)
        $currentId = 0;
        else
        $currentId++;
        
        $(".image-popup img").attr("src", $images[$currentId]);
        
        
        
    });
    
$(".image-popup .navbtn#prev").on("click", function(e){
        
        e.stopPropagation();
        
        
        if($currentId == 0)
        $currentId = $images.length - 1;
        else
        $currentId--;
        
        $(".image-popup img").attr("src", $images[$currentId]);
        
        
        
    });    
    </script>
</html>
```

You can find all code here: https://jsfiddle.net/maartendemoor/60wbaut1/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not answer to your question but I would suggest you re-write it in vanilla. This will solve your problem and increase performance.

Comment: `$(window).on("load")
{` is not what you want

Comment: and having over 30Mb of images doesn't help either

Comment: @certainperformance I don't understand your comment?